# How to select a single node from an XML document?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, exception

I want to read data from the XML response from API i.e [wunderground API for weather forecasting](http://api.wunderground.com/api/c94ec600fe494bc2/astronomy/q/Cayman/Grand.xml). I have used the below code to read it.

```
    HttpWebRequest GoogleRequest;
    HttpWebResponse GoogleResponse = null;
    XmlDocument GoogleXMLdoc = null;
    try
    {
        GoogleRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.wunderground.com/api/c94ec600fe494bc2/astronomy/q/Cayman/Grand.xml");
        GoogleResponse = (HttpWebResponse)GoogleRequest.GetResponse();
        GoogleXMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
        GoogleXMLdoc.Load(GoogleResponse.GetResponseStream());

        XmlNode root = GoogleXMLdoc.DocumentElement;

        //XmlNodeList nodeList1 = root.SelectNodes("/sunset/");
        XmlNode test = root.SelectSingleNode("/moon_phase/");
     }
//.....
```

But I am exception **expression must evaluate to a node-set**  on the last line of the code. I have tried some solutions but I was not able to get the data. Actually what want is: I want to get the sun set and sunrise time. Please help me how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want get xml via xpath you should get such as this:

```
    XmlNode test = root.SelectSingleNode("//moon_phase/percentIlluminated");
```

Or

```
        XmlNode test = root.SelectSingleNode("//moon_phase/*");
```

Or

```
GoogleXMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("//moon_phase[0]");
```

This is your result:

```
<version>0.1</version><termsofService>http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html</termsofService>
<features><feature>astronomy</feature></features>
<moon_phase><percentIlluminated>91</percentIlluminated><ageOfMoon>12</ageOfMoon><current_time><hour>1</hour><minute>51</minute></current_time><sunset><hour>17</hour><minute>50</minute></sunset><sunrise><hour>6</hour><minute>51</minute></sunrise></moon_phase><sun_phase><sunset><hour>17</hour><minute>50</minute></sunset><sunrise><hour>6</hour><minute>51</minute></sunrise></sun_phase>
```

See this [Site](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html):

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

Select the document node

/

Select the 'root' element

/root

Select all 'actor' elements that are direct children of the 'actors' element.

/root/actors/actor

Select all 'singer' elements regardless of their positions in the document.

//foo:singer

Select the 'id' attributes of the 'singer' elements regardless of their positions in the document.

//foo:singer/@id

Select the textual value of first 'actor' element.

//actor[1](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)/text()

Select the last 'actor' element.

//actor[last()]

Select the first and second 'actor' elements using their position.

//actor[position() < 3]

Select all 'actor' elements that have an 'id' attribute.

//actor[@id]

Select the 'actor' element with the 'id' attribute value of '3'.

//actor[@id='3']

Select all 'actor' nodes with the 'id' attribute value lower or equal to '3'.

//actor[@id<=3]

Select all the children of the 'singers' node.

/root/foo:singers/*

Select all the elements in the document.

//*

Select all the 'actor' elements AND the 'singer' elements.

//actor|//foo:singer

Select the name of the first element in the document.

name(//*[1](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html))

Select the numeric value of the 'id' attribute of the first 'actor' element.
number(//actor[1](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)/@id)

Select the string representation value of the 'id' attribute of the first 'actor' element.

string(//actor[1](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)/@id)

Select the length of the first 'actor' element's textual value.

string-length(//actor[1](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)/text())

Select the local name of the first 'singer' element, i.e. without the namespace.

local-name(//foo:singer[1](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html))

Select the number of 'singer' elements.

count(//foo:singer)
 Select the sum of the 'id' attributes of the 'singer' elements.

sum(//foo:singer/@id)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
GoogleXMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("//moon_phase[0]");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea(not test)! The expression given evaluates to a boolean, not a node-set.

Try this:

```
XmlNode test = root.SelectNodes("//moon_phase/")[0];
```

Or

```
XmlNode test = root.SelectNodes("//moon_phase[yourAttribute='something']") ;
```